# Read/Write Large Amounts of Data

Tags: vba, excel, large-data

I'm working on copying large amounts of data from one spreadsheet to the other 160 spreadsheets in the workbook. Currently, Excel (2013) runs into an error as it does not have enough resources to complete the operation.

My goal is to copy data in the range V13:XI1150 in sheet 4 to sheets 5-160. I tried splitting up the range that the code is stored in (see variables rng1 and rng2), as well as grouping 10 worksheets together (although I realize this has little effect).

Is there a way to streamline the code I'm working on here so I can successfully copy this data over?

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub copypaste()

'''''''''Globals'''''''''''''

Dim j As Long 'Loop control variable
Dim sheetstart As Integer 'starting sheet variable
Dim sheetend As Integer 'ending sheet variable
Dim rng1 As Range 'range to copy
Dim rng2 As Range 'Second range

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'Sets manual calculation
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Turns off screen updating


sheetstart = 5 'first sheet to copy over in loop
sheetend = 15 'last sheeet to copy over in loop

With Sheets(4) 'Selects the 4th sheet
    Set rng1 = Range("V13:LO1150") 'Stores first half of data in rng
    Set rng2 = Range("LP13:XI1150") 'Stores second half of data in rng
End With


For j = 1 To 16 'loops through all groups of 10 sheets
    copypaste10 rng1, sheetstart, sheetend 'calls copypaste10 function
    copypaste10 rng2, sheetstart, sheetend 'calls copypaste10 function
    sheetstart = sheetstart + 10 'increments to next 10 sheets
    sheetend = sheetend + 10 'increments to next 10 sheets

    Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'Sets auto calculation
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Turns on screen updating


End Sub


Public Function copypaste10(rng As Range, sstart As Integer, sstop As Integer)
'''''''''Locals'''''''''''''
    Dim i As Long 'Loop control
    Dim WS As Worksheet 'worksheet being worked on
    Dim ArrayOne() As String 'Array of sheets we are working on

    ReDim ArrayOne(sstart To sstop) 'Array of sheets

''''''''''Calcuations'''''''''''''
    For i = sstart To sstop
        ArrayOne(i) = Sheets(i).Name
    Next

    For Each WS In Sheets(ArrayOne)
        WS.Rows(2).Resize(rng.Count).Copy
        rng.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("v13")
        Next WS


End Function
```

Comment: Are there enough resources to copy the data to a single destination worksheet rather than all 155 worksheets?

Comment: There is enough to copy over to one sheet.

Comment: It's almost certain that the problem is with the calculation then, and not the copy/paste.  You will most likely need to save each sheet in a separate workbook after copying the data to it, then closing that workbook before moving on to the next sheet.  That should keep the recalculations from bringing your system down.

Answer (score 1):

I ran a quick test with the following code, and it ran just fine:

```
Sub test()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("V13:XI1150")
    rng.Copy

    For i = 2 To 161
        Sheets(i).Select
        Range("V13").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

There was only static data in my test cells, not formulas.  That may make the difference, because when you turn Automatic Calculation back on, that will be a gigantic hit to your system resources, especially if it is a complex calculation in your cells.

Comment: All my data is formulas, I'll try keeping the auto calc off and/or turning it on in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

It could be extra Copy that you're doing in your loop i.e.

```
WS.Rows(2).Resize(rng.Count).Copy
```

That copy will store to memory even though you don't seem to be pasting it anywhere (to be honest though, I'm not sure whether or not that i.e. the clipboard will clear that after exiting the function or as needed)

Nonetheless, this is an alternate solution if you don't have formulas in your range origin.
Since your destination is always the same, and your origin ranges are the same dimension (just different starting points), you can avoid the copy / paste all together :

```
For Each WS In Sheets(ArrayOne)
    WS.Range("V13:LO1150") = rng.Value
Next WS
```

Again, note that it will only copy the values over to your destination sheets

****--EDIT--****

If you do need the formulas you can change `.Value` to `.Formula`, but note that this will "paste" formulas that refer to the origin sheet, not the relative references of your destination sheet. I would also turn auto calculations off before running the macro (`Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`, and either calculate or turn on calculations at the end (`Application.Calculation =xlCalculationAutomatic`) or maybe after every few "pastes" by using `Application.Calculate`.